# Shiny Error when Filtering Data

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny app where a check box group will filter the data. I have the following files:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

tags$head(
tags$style(HTML("

 .multicol {

   -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

   -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */

   column-count: 3;

 }

"))

),


titlePanel(h1('NBA MVPs', align = "center")),
      hr(),
      mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(type='tabs',
            tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
            tabPanel("Description",
                     p('Blah blah blah')))),
 hr(),
fluidRow(
column(2,
       radioButtons('stat', "Statistics", choices=c('Field Goal %'='FG.Perc', '3 Pt. %'='ThreePointPerc',"Free Throw %" = "FTPerc", "Rebounds" = "TRB", "Assists" ="ASST", 'Steals' = "STL", "Points" = "PTS", "True Shooting %"= "TrueShootingPerc", "Eff. FG %"= "eFG", "Total Reb. %" = "TRBPerc", "Off. Rating" = "ORtg", "Def. Rating" = "DRtg")))
),

 wellPanel(
tags$div(class = "multicol", checkboxGroupInput("player", choices = c("Player1" = '1',  "Player2" = '2'), selected = c('1', '2')
      ))
 )

))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny); library(dplyr); library(ggvis); library(mosaic)
data= PlayerData

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  plotData <- reactive({ 
df <- data %>%
  filter(player %in% input$player)
})
 output$plot <- renderPlot(xyplot(FG~Rk, group=player, data=plotData(), auto.key=list(space='top', columns=2, lines=TRUE, points=FALSE, panel=function(x,y){
panel.xyplot(x,y)
panel.abline(h=0, col='red')
 }))
 )
 })
```

When I run the application with the code above, the interface appears fine, but the plot does not appear and I get the error: "unused argument (by = `_vars`)". However, if I removed the line that filters the data in the server file, the plot appears without the error. The data contains a column with the name 'player' that contains either '1' or '2'.

I am not sure why this filtering line would cause an error, but I am not as familiar with the CSS used to get multiple columns for the check boxes, so I suspect this might be causing an issue.

Comment: First, add a line `df` in the reactive at the end. That will actually return the data frame.